# How to change these for loops to numpy operation

Tags: python, numpy

The following is my code:

```
avg = 0
for i in range((masks.shape[0])):
    nz = np.count_nonzero(masks[i])
    avg += nz
avg /= masks.shape[0]
index = []
for i in range((masks.shape[0])):
    if np.count_nonzero(masks[i]) >= 2*avg/3:
        index.append(i)
masks = masks[index]
```

The mask is an array of shape [4,1,640,480]

I want to change these codes to numpy operations, but i do not know how.

Comment: What have you tried, exactly? Stack Overflow is not the place to drop off your work for others to do. You haven't even shared enough for us to run your program. Please see: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/11301900, [mcve].

Comment: @Konchog Of all the words to forget...

Comment: If the iteration axis small (like 4), the loop might not be costing much time.  A few loops on a complex task might actually be faster

Answer (score 0):

The first loop is not necessary `np.count_nonzero(masks)` on the whole array is the same as summing up the calls on the first dimension. Then, you can pass a tuple as the axis argument to `np.count_nonzero` (see also [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html)), to get the number of non-zero elements for element on the first axis:

```py
avg = np.count_nonzero(masks) / masks.shape[0]
index = np.count_nonzero(masks, axis=(1,2,3)) > 2 * avg / 3
masks = masks[index]
```